# R square in mixed model with random effects

Tags: mixed-model, r-squared

For mixed models with random intercepts only, the statistic for R square is

$$R^2 = (V_{int\ only} - V_{full\ model}) / V_{int\ only}$$

My question is: How to estimate R square in mixed models with random effects? And estimate R square for each level? Let's say it's a 3-level model with random effects of time at level 2.

Answer (score 20):

The R package MuMIn also now has a function for calculating Nakagawa and Schielzeth's r-squared for mixed models.  That is the function `r.squaredGLMM()` and you simply feed it a lmer object (from package lme4) to obtain the values.
MuMIn has [excellent documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MuMIn/MuMIn.pdf) so you should be able to learn any details there.

Answer (score 10):

The following paper was just published and may give you the answer to your question:

> Nakagawa, S. and Schielzeth, H. (2012). [A general and simple method for obtaining $R^2$  from generalized linear mixed-effects models](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.2041-210x.2012.00261.x/abstract). *Methods in Ecology and Evolution*, in press.
>   DOI: 10.1111/j.2041-210x.2012.00261.x