# How do we calculate the $R^2$ statistic for a mixed model with one random intercept only?

Tags: model, r-squared, mixed-model

I have read in previous posts that for mixed models with random intercepts only, the statistic for $R^2$ is

$$R^2 = \frac{\text{V of intercept only model} − \text{V of full model}}{\text{V of intercept only model}}$$

You can check the post here: 
[R square in mixed model with random effects](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46160/r-square-in-mixed-model-with-random-effects)

1. Is the formula correct?
2. What does $V$ correspond to?
3. Does the intercept only model include the random intercept too?

Comment: I am not sure, as I have used the same structure used in this post:
http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46160/r-square-in-mixed-model-with-random-effects

@user777

Comment: I overlooked that you asked my precise question in your post. Apologies.

Comment: Perhaps @NonSleeper can help me with this?