# Linear mixed effects model fit

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, random-effects-model, r-squared

I have a linear mixed effects model in R:

```
model<-lmer(response ~ v1 + v2 + v3 + (1|group), data=df)
summary(model)
confint(model)
```

I'm interested in the effect of `v1` and `v2` on my `response` so I'd be reporting their coefficients and confidence intervals, but I also want to report some indication of the overall model fit (how well the predictor variables are capturing the total variance of my response). Ideally I'm looking for something that is analogous to the adjusted R2 from fixed effects models

What is the typical way to do this for mixed-effects models? And more importantly, is there a way to get a significance test associated with the corresponding R2 value?

Comment: Does this help you http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46160/r-square-in-mixed-model-with-random-effects ? Have a look here too https://jonlefcheck.net/2013/03/13/r2-for-linear-mixed-effects-models/

Comment: Is it possible to get any sort of p value for those R2 values?