# Extract all R2 values from LMM

Tags: r, mixed-model, r-squared

In order to analyse which factors have greater weight in the proportion of incidence (number of infected individuals against total individuals), the interaction of all factors (habitat, site and seasons) must be tested by a linear mixed model (LMM)

The predictor variables are habitat and season, considering at the same time the random factor sampling site and the response factor was the incidence value.

The dataset that I am using is this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fVuJNdZ593L6LoIKNhUynRGGIsN-IdxV/view?usp=sharing

I performed the GLMM by R. Habitat and season as fixed factor and site as random

```
 m1 <- nlme::lme(Incidence ~ Habitat + Season, random = ~1|Site, data=Incidence)
```

In order to extract the R2

```
      r2 <- r2glmm::r2beta(model=m1,partial=TRUE,method='sgv')
    
    print(r2)

        Effect   Rsq upper.CL lower.CL
                Model 0.867    0.929    0.792
          HabitatEdge 0.705    0.836    0.539
         HabitatWasteland 0.639    0.797    0.443
       HabitatOakwood 0.603    0.775    0.394
         SeasonSummer 0.084    0.348    0.000
         SeasonSpring 0.003    0.184    0.000
```

I would like to obtain the R2 of all habitat (included Crop) and all seasons (included Autumn), this analysis took them as "Model".

Using summary function, those factors (crop and autumn) are masked by Intercept

What can I do?

Comment: Aren't those factor levels used as the reference levels in your model (like, `summary()` won't print the corresponding regression coefficient either)?

Comment: Using summary function,  those factors (crop and autumn) are masked by Intercept, and I can not know these values.

Comment: Relevel your factor (i.e. change the reference category) or use `C` or `contrasts`. See [Coding for categorical variables in regression models](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/modules/coding-for-categorical-variables-in-regression-models/).

Comment: I don't know this package, but why is it printing an $R^2$  value for each factor level, and not for the factor itself? See also this [related thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/46160/930).

Comment: r.squaredGLMM() provide the Marginal R-Squared and Conditional R-Squared but not the R-squared of each element